# Trouble shredding an xml document into a table using .nodes() and cross apply

Tags: sql-server, xml, nodes, cross-apply

I have an xml document that defines a table's indexes.
Here is an example:

```
<TargetDatabaseChanges>
     <Tables>
        <Table TName="Replacement" Schema="dbo" TextImageOnFileGroup="PRIMARY">
            <Indexes>
                <Index IndexName="IX_InventoryId" PrimaryKeyIndex="0" IndexDescription="NONCLUSTERED" PadIndex="0" Statistics_NoRecompute="0" IgnoreDupKey="0" AllowRowLocks="1" AllowPageLocks="1">
                  <IndexColumn ICName="ProductId" IsDescendingSort="0" OrdinalPosition="1" />
                </Index>
                <Index IndexName="IX_VendorId" PrimaryKeyIndex="0" IndexDescription="NONCLUSTERED" PadIndex="0" Statistics_NoRecompute="0" IgnoreDupKey="0" AllowRowLocks="1" AllowPageLocks="1">
                  <IndexColumn ICName="VendorId" IsDescendingSort="0" OrdinalPosition="1" />
                </Index>
            </Indexes>
        </Table>
        <Table TName="Activity" Schema="dbo" TextImageOnFileGroup="PRIMARY">
            <Indexes>
                 <Index IndexName="IX_ApplicationId" PrimaryKeyIndex="0" IsUnique="0" IndexDescription="NONCLUSTERED" PadIndex="0" Statistics_NoRecompute="0" IgnoreDupKey="0" AllowRowLocks="1" AllowPageLocks="1">
                    <IndexColumn ICName="ApplicationId" IsDescendingSort="0" OrdinalPosition="1" />
                </Index>
            </Indexes>
        </Table>
     </Tables>
</TargetDatabaseChanges>
```

When the table has 2 indexes with a different column associated with each index, I get 4 rows of data when I should only get 2 rows.

This is my select statement:

```
SELECT DBTables.Name.value('@TName', 'varchar(100)') AS TableName, DBTables.Name.value('@Schema', 'varchar(20)') AS SchemaName, 
        [Indexes].I.value('@IndexName', 'varchar(100)') AS IndexName,  [Indexes].I.value('@PrimaryKeyIndex', 'varchar(1)') AS PrimaryKeyIndex,  [Indexes].I.value('@IsUnique', 'varchar(1)') AS IsUnique, 
            [Indexes].I.value('@IndexDescription', 'varchar(120)') AS IndexDescription,
            [Indexes].I.value('@PadIndex', 'varchar(1)') AS PadIndex, [Indexes].I.value('@Statistics_NoRecompute', 'varchar(1)') AS StatisticsNoRecompute, [Indexes].I.value('@IgnoreDupKey', 'varchar(1)') AS IgnoreDupKey,
            [Indexes].I.value('@AllowRowLocks', 'varchar(1)') AS AllowRowLocks, [Indexes].I.value('@AllowPageLocks', 'varchar(1)') AS AllowPageLocks,
        [IndexColumn].IC.value('@ICName', 'varchar(100)') AS IndexColumnName, [IndexColumn].IC.value('@IsDescendingSort', 'varchar(1)') AS IsDescendingSort, 
        [IndexColumn].IC.value('@OrdinalPosition', 'varchar(2)') AS OrdinalPosition
FROM @XmlDBChanges.nodes('/TargetDatabaseChanges/Tables/Table') AS DBTables(Name)               
        CROSS APPLY DBTables.Name.nodes('Indexes/Index[@PrimaryKeyIndex=0]') AS [Indexes](I)
        CROSS APPLY DBTables.Name.nodes('Indexes/Index[@PrimaryKeyIndex=0]/IndexColumn') AS [IndexColumn](IC)
```

This is the table of the table with 2 indexes:

```
Replacement dbo IX_InventoryId  0   NULL    NONCLUSTERED    0   0   0   1   1   ProductId   0   1
Replacement dbo IX_InventoryId  0   NULL    NONCLUSTERED    0   0   0   1   1   VendorId    0   1
Replacement dbo IX_VendorId 0   NULL    NONCLUSTERED    0   0   0   1   1   ProductId   0   1
Replacement dbo IX_VendorId 0   NULL    NONCLUSTERED    0   0   0   1   1   VendorId    0   1
```

The row that associates the index IX_InventoryId with the column VendorID should not exist.  The same with the row IX_VendorId with the column ProductId.

It seems that the `CROSS APPLY DBTables.Name.nodes('Indexes/Index[@PrimaryKeyIndex=0]/IndexColumn') AS [IndexColumn](IC)`  is doing this incorrect association but I don't know how to limit it to only the `IndexColumn` for the correct Index.

How to limit this association?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out...in case anybody else needs the help...
I changed the last `CROSS APPLY`:

```
CROSS APPLY DBTables.Name.nodes('Indexes/Index[@PrimaryKeyIndex=0]/IndexColumn') AS [IndexColumn](IC)
```

To this:

```
CROSS APPLY I.nodes('IndexColumn') AS [IndexColumn](IC)
```

The `I` is from the previous `CROSS APPLY'
So the`FROM` clause looks like this:

```
`FROM @XmlDBChanges.nodes('/TargetDatabaseChanges/Tables/Table') AS DBTables(Name)              
        CROSS APPLY DBTables.Name.nodes('Indexes/Index[@PrimaryKeyIndex=0]') AS [Indexes](I)
        CROSS APPLY I.nodes('IndexColumn') AS [IndexColumn](IC)`
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need in `cross apply`. You can access everything in a query like this.

```
select t.v.value('../../../@TName','varchar(100)') TName,
t.v.value('../@IndexName','varchar(100)') IndexName,
t.v.value('@ICName','varchar(100)') ICName
from @x.nodes('TargetDatabaseChanges/Tables/Table/Indexes/Index/IndexColumn') t(v)
--if you want to filter
--from @x.nodes('TargetDatabaseChanges/Tables/Table/Indexes/Index[@PrimaryKeyIndex="0"]/IndexColumn') t(v)
```